# Change wp query depending on year selection

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming, blogs

**Introduction**

I have a blog where I am showing latest post within the last 365 days and only show 100 post. I also have the option for the user to select year (this is what im currently working on).

**Question**

How can I have it so when A user chooses a different year (from the selection) the query is set to show post from that year and remove the 100 post limit and show this is my blog page.

**My Query**

```
<?php
// gets info
$current_category = get_queried_object('post');
//$current_user =get_the_author_posts();

// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => $current_category->term_id,
//    'author' =>  $current_user,
//    'tag' => '',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
//            'year'  => '2019',
            'after' => '-365 days',
            'column' => 'post_date',
        )
    )
));
```

**My Selection (year)**

```
 <select style="top: -4px;"
                class=" btn-link col-12"
                name="archive-dropdown"
                onChange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
            <?php wp_get_archives('type=yearly&format=option'); ?>
        </select>
```

**My Blog Page**

```
<?php
require "settings.php";
if ($wpb_all_query->have_posts())
    :while ($wpb_all_query->have_posts())
    :$wpb_all_query->the_post();
    ?>
content
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I was trying a statement in the query but could not see how to get year selected , but then if i set the year to a var depending on the option maybe that's better>?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all posts (no limit to 100), for the year 1999. Change `$yearToLookFor` to the year you need.

```
<?php
//here is from a $_GET parameter
$yearToLookFor = $_GET['year'];

 // gets info
 $current_category = get_queried_object('post');
//$current_user =get_the_author_posts();

// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => $current_category->term_id,
//    'author' =>  $current_user,
//    'tag' => '',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $yearToLookFor,

        )
    )
));
```

In this example, the year got taken from a url query, like this: https://yourwebiste.zyx/?year=1999

Comment: yes, thats true. however how do I change the variable for year dynamically

Comment: I update my answer to show you one example on how to change it

Comment: ok, but how do i set the url query on my selection part